# LEFT JOIN much faster than INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join, explain

I have two tables ->

- users

  ```
  user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  username VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
  ```
- pings

  ```
  ping_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PPRIMARY KEY
  disqus_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
  user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL

  INDEX combo1(disqus_id,user_id)
  ```

I run this query ->

```
EXPLAIN SELECT pings.*, username
          FROM pings
    INNER JOIN users USING(user_id)
         WHERE pings.disqus_id = 'post_168' AND user_id = '1'
      ORDER BY pings.ping_id DESC LIMIT 2
```

The `Extra`column under pimgs says `Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort` and under users says `Using where; Using join buffer`.

I run this query ->

```
EXPLAIN SELECT pings.*, username
          FROM pings
     LEFT JOIN users USING(user_id)
         WHERE pings.disqus_id = 'post_168' AND user_id = '1'
      ORDER BY pings.ping_id DESC LIMIT 2
```

The `Extra`column under pimgs says `Using where` and under users it is empty.

What is happening?

Comment: How long does each one take?

Comment: You realize that an `INNER JOIN` and a `LEFT JOIN` are different types of queries that have a very different effect on your result set.

Comment: can u explain in detail @CAbbott

Comment: @CAbbott: That's true in general, but not in all specific cases. Example #1: if you know that every `ping` record does have a corresponding `users` record. Example #2: if something else in the query filters out all records without `users` fields.

Comment: @CAbbott - You are right.  But in this case where the user_id is NOT NULL in both tables, will it make any difference?

Comment: @RayZ: See ["Join (SQL)" on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: @Slowcoder - it depends on the values of `user_id` in the `pings` table and if they exist in the `users`.

Comment: @ruakh - true enough. But the point I was making was that they're 2 inherently different queries that produce different plans. In this case they may just happen to produce the same result set.

Comment: @CAbbott - Right.  I realized it just after I posted my comment.

Answer (score 2):

- The [USING(column_list)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html) clause names a list of columns that must exist in both tables.

so if you are using `user_id` must be in both tables , but left join will return the values in table a and not in table b

The following two clauses are semantically identical:

```
a LEFT JOIN b USING (c1,c2,c3)
a LEFT JOIN b ON a.c1=b.c1 AND a.c2=b.c2 AND a.c3=b.c3
```

Answer (score 2):

You're creating 2 different queries that have 2 different sets of requirements for producing, what may happen to be, the same result set:

**Query 1: (INNER JOIN)**: You're stating that it can only return rows from table `ping` where there is a matching `user_id` value in the table `users`. That's why there's extra `using`s for checking.

**Query 2: (LEFT JOIN)**: You're stating that it can return *all rows* from table `ping` and *any rows that match* `user_id` from table `users`.

The distinguishing issue here is whether or not you're **requiring** that there be a matching value in the second table. In Query 1 it has to add extra checking to ensure that there's a matching value, in Query 2, it doesn't.